# Unity InputField box always in focus

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, textbox, enter

I am trying to create a simple math game in unity where player enters the answer to a math problem.  Essentially all the user can do is type in answer and then enter.

Currently, I have it that user can enter into the input field, after they enter, when the next problem appears, they have to physically click on input field box again to enter the answer.

Is there a way to make it so you can enter the input field continuously without having to re-click the input-field?

### Edit Below:

i put in the code below. How do i grab the inputfield if i get error Cannot implicitly covert type inputfield to gameobject.

```
GameObject inputField;
void Start()
{
    GameObject inputField = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
    inputField.Select();
    inputField.ActivateInputField();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can autofocus the `InputField` by calling [`ActivateInputField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.ActivateInputField.html) after loading a new "problem". Not sure but maybe you also need to [`Select`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.Select.html) it first

```c#
// Not sure if this is needed
theInputField.Select();

theInputField.ActivateInputField();
```

---

Alternatively you can also listen for submissions and do e.g.

```c#
private void Start ()
{
    // Make your InputField accept multiple lines
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.LineType.MultiLineNewline.html
    theInputField.lineType = InputField.LineType.MultiLineNewline;
    // Instead of waiting for submissions use the return key
    theInputField.onValidateInput += MyValidate;
}

private char MyValidate(string currentText, int currentIndex, char addedCharToValidate)
{
    // Checks if a new line is entered
    if (addedCharToValidate == '\n')
    {
        // if so treat it as submission
        // -> clear the input and evaluate
        EvaluateInput(theInputField.text.Trim('\0'));
        theInputField.text = "";
        return '\0';
    }
    return addedCharToValidate;
}
```

So actually the User never leaves the `InputField` at all.

Comment: Why is your `inputField` a `GameObject` and not simply `InputField inputField;` ? And doing it in `Start` is probably not enough .. you would do it after every submission ;)